# How to show current command execution time in tmux status line

Tags: tmux

I'm wondering if I can get a current command execution time (while command is executing) shown somewhere in the tmux's status line?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit old but as I came across this while researching this, here's the answer:

```
for pid in $(tmux list-panes -a -F '#{pane_pid}'); do
  for child in $(pgrep -P $pid); do
    ps -p $child -ho etime,comm,args;
  done;
done
```

Breaking it down:

First, we get the "first PIDs" for every TMUX pane, change this to narrow down which panels you want to include in your results:

```
tmux list-panes -a -F '#{pane_pid}'
```

"First PIDs" mean the PID of the shell, so it'll most likely be your shell (Fish, ZSH, Bash etc). So now we use a `for` loop to iterate over those PIDs, and for each PID we get the PIDs of processes spawned by that PID, i.e. their children, which is done, inside the loop, by:

```
pgrep -P $pid
```

Now we have the child PIDs for each pane, which we can pass to `ps` to get data on the process. `etime` is the elapsed time since the process started, `comm` is the command, and `args` are the actual arguments, including the actual path of the command being run:

```
ps -p $child -ho etime,comm,args
```

The `-h` flag tells `ps` to not print the header, while the `-o` flag sets the output, in this case it's three columns, `etime`, `comm` and `args`.

It's a bit messy as a one-liner, but works:

```
for pid in $(tmux list-panes -a -F '#{pane_pid}'); do for child in $(pgrep -P $pid); do ps -p $child -ho etime,comm,args; done; done
```

Or, if you use fish-shell like me, it gets a bit better, though it's still not as clean as I'd like:

```
 for pid in (tmux list-panes -a -F '#{pane_pid}'); for child in (pgrep -P $pid); ps -p $child -ho etime,comm,args; end; end
```

Still, this does the job, although a bit hackishly. Though, keep in mind, this doesn't check whether the process is running in the foreground, so if you daemonize stuff (`&`, using Ctrl+Z etc) you will get data for those too, filtering daemons, pipes or whatever may be possible but I wanted all the data so I didn't look into any of those.

Comment: Maybe you could be more verbose and post what exactly should be added to `~/.tmuxrc` for this information to appear in the status line?